# Floating point value of 0 greater than 0

Tags: c, floating-point

I can't reproduce this with a simple program, but somewhere in my program I have something like:

```
float e = f(...);
if (e > 0.0f) {
    ...
```

`printf("%f", e)` shows that `e` is `0.000000`, yet `e > 0.0f` is true... So is `e > 0` and `e > 0.0`. What am I missing?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html TL;DR: Whenever you use floating point values, there is almost always a chance of rounding errors. Therefore, you should always compare floating point values within a small range, not for equality to a specific value.

Comment: [Accuracy problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) are a common problem with floating point numbers.

Comment: This isn't a floating-point accuracy problem, it's a format string problem; `printf(%f)` is printing a non-zero number as zero, as both answers observe, because the questioner has explicitly asked it to do so (whether they realize it or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the floating point value is greater than 0, but less than the precision that printf uses to print floating point numbers with `%f`.  You can use `%e` or `%g` for better results as illustrated with the following program.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
  int i;
  float e;

  for (i = 1; i < 64; i++) {
    printf("Decimal places: %d\n", i);

    e = 1.0 / pow(10, i);

    if (e > 0.0f) {
      printf("Value displayed with %%e: %e > 0.0f\n", e);
      printf("Value displayed with %%f: %f > 0.0f\n", e);
      printf("Value displayed with %%g: %g > 0.0f\n\n", e);

    }
  }
}
```

*You will need to compile this with the maths library*.  *For gcc use: `-lm`*

Answer (score 6):

The floating point value is larger than zero, but less than 1e-7. It's printing issue. Use scientific notation printf("%e", value); or "%g" for shortest notation.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `printf("%f", e)` shows it to be zero doesn't mean anything, because `printf` rounds the value both to decimal floating point and to the precision of the output, so very small numbers larger than 0 are likely to be put out as 0.

Try `printf("%e", e)` or `printf("%.17f", e)` and see what happens.

Comment: `1.17f` may still print a non-zero value as zero; `%e` is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `e` is actually not zero.  It has some tiny value in it, but that gets hidden because `%f` converts to decimal, losing precision.  Use `printf("%e",e)` instead as your debug statement, and you will see that there is a nonzero value in there.